# How can I fetch user photo from zkteco device?

Tags: c#, asp.net, zkteco

i am using zkteco bio metric machine with c#. i fetched successfully Employee name and Enroll Number with the help of zkemkeeper. 
Can anybody Guide me about how to grab employee photo from zkteco machine.

Comment: I always look at the SDK -> https://www.zkteco.com/en/download_catgory/46.html

Comment: i am using the following sdk https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/%2FArticles%2F1104538%2FCsharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started
can u exact guide which method fetch employee images

Comment: try their software (zk Iclock) , if you can access the image using their software then try do more search if you cannot find any result about your need I suggest to contact their support.