# How to get user photo from zkteco?

Tags: c#, biometrics, zkteco

im doing an app in c# using a biometric device.
From the device I already can get the id,time,date,etc... But I didnt found a way to get the photo and the name and I know its possible.

Ive been searching for a while and i found a similar question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059577/how-can-i-fetch-user-photo-from-zkteco-device)
that led me to this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started Idownloaded the guide manual and read it all but i didnt found anything about the user's name and photo.

The method that im using to get user's data is the following:

```
public bool GetUserInfo(int dwMachineNumber, int dwEnrollNumber, ref string Name, ref string Password, ref int Privilege, ref bool Enabled)
        {
            return GetUserInfo(dwMachineNumber, dwEnrollNumber, ref Name, ref Password, ref Privilege, ref Enabled);
        }
```

With some minor changes to adapt to my code.